# Close Socket in Django - Error: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, django

I accidentally created an infinite loop on an api call. It got out of hand and I had to shut it down [control + C].

now when I do

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I get

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
August 08, 2013 - 12:43:41
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'summertime.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Does anyone know how to reset the socket? Can I just shut down my computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options the first one is choice another port:

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

and the other one is killing the process in the port, to `find the process`:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8000
```

to `kill the process`:

```
kill -9 <pid-of-process>
```

Answer (score 8):

to see if you already have runserver going use

```
ps -ef | grep runserver
```

to kill it use

```
pkill -9 -f runserver
```

(pkill kills things by name)

Comment: `pkill -9 -f runserver` working for py3:django2 in 2018